# This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.ts(2354) on VS Code(but not on build/dev)

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a repository and getting a warning in the editor:

```
This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.ts(2354)
```

This appears by example just on the @Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-authenticated-layout',
  templateUrl: './authenticated-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./authenticated-layout.component.scss'],
})
```

But, if I use `ng serve`, it work nicely.
I've searched a bit, but in the other case, it seems that the `npm install` wasn't run.

Often if I close VS Code and reopen it, it works again.

Here is my package.json if it helps:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --configuration=en",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint --fix",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.3.2",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.3.2",
    "@ngxs/schematics": "^0.0.1-alpha.5",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.3.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^8.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-indicators": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^9.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^7.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-messages": "^1.32.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^3.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-typography": "^2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.5.12",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "^0.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "primeflex": "^3.1.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.3",
    "@ngxs/schematics": "^0.0.1-alpha.5",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.17.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "git-pull-run": "^1.0.2",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "ng-mocks": "^13.4.1",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^13.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

Any idea what is going on?